# Getting ‘Command not found’ errors when there is no space after the opening square bracket

Tags: linux, bash

```
i=0
for f in `awk '{print $1}' config.list`
do
    echo "i value is $i"
    if ["$i" = "0"]
    then
        echo "here"
        i=$((i+1))
        continue 
    fi
    arr[i]=$f  
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

In the above bash script I am getting an error where i have used the if statement it looks like this

```
./script.sh: line 5: [0: command not found
```

Kindly point me out what could be my mistake.

Comment: @jedwards, a single equal sign is correct for string equality comparison. With `[[` the double equal sign is for pattern matching. You may be thinking of another language.

Comment: @glennjackman, [I realize `=` and `==` are synonymous](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html), my statement was more for readability and maintainability.  Traditionally `=` is for assignment and should be left that way whenever possible (e.g. this case).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `if [ "$i" = "0" ]`

In bash, you need spaces around `[` and `]` in `if` conditions

Answer (score 4):

You are getting this error, because Bash if statements require the addition of spaces around the operands:

```
if [ "$i" = "0" ]
```